# Maven tries to fetch shrinkwrap-bom from maven central, instead of configured repository

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-3

I am trying to build my `maven` project using Maven version `3.3.9` and a custom maven repository.

Building the project with Maven `3.1.0`, it runs, downloads the dependencies and passes the tests.

After removing all local dependencies and upgrading Maven to 3.3.9, I get the following error while in the download phase:

```
failed to execute goal on project ... could not resolve dependencies ... 
failed to collect dependencies at org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final:
failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:
could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom.pom:1.2.2 from/to central (...)
Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org
```

Note again, that I am using a custom repository, not Maven Central.

But it works for the older version of Maven, so `settings.xml` is configured for my repository and the artifact does exist there.
Also, other dependencies do successfully download, it's just this dependency.

Why is Maven still trying to fetch from Maven Central regardless of my repository settings?

Comment: Firewall / Network issue...cause the given artifact does exist in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-validator%22%20AND%20v%3A%225.2.4.Final%22).

Comment: I said I'm using custom repository, not the central... And the older maven version does work

Comment: Additional information for the question belongs into the question (edit it), not into commends (which may be deleted). I added it for you.

Comment: If Maven writes "Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org", it tries to contact MavenCentral, but cannot. It is possible that your new version does not find the settings.xml. It is furthermore possible, that you installed an additional artifact into the local repository before you deleted it to start anew.

Comment: It does download other artifacts from the custom repository. And I did say the repo is custom in the first sentence...

Comment: @itaied Sure you said that. And I said that your Maven is trying to contact MavenCentral. Of course, it could contact both. But this implies that your settings.xml is probably read by your Maven and the error is not a missing or wrong settings.xml

Comment: By the way: Is org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final actually in your "custom repository"?

Comment: Yes. The weird thing is maven 3.1.0 works.. it finds and downloads it...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. 
Our setup uses Nexus 3 repository manager. Maven Central is set up as a proxy repo in Nexus.

I have made the mistake to list central in the repositories part of settings.xml

```
<repositories>
...
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://<MY_NEXUS_HOST>:8081/repository/maven-central/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**This was working for most of the dependencies.** However it wasn't working for org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom. Only this one.

The resolution was to specify Maven Central as a *mirror*:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central-proxy</id>
        <name>central-proxy</name>
        <url>http://<MY_NEXUS_HOST>:8081/repository/maven-central/</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: Now, I also ran into this, and hugely appreciate the answer -  but do you have any idea what's happening here/why this is happening?

Comment: Let's say you use an external dependency that is not stored in central but in its own repo.
This dependency's pom.xml will state this repo in its <repositories> section.
Now you want to use this behind a corporate firewall, so you set up your nexus mirror. 
You cannot edit the pom of the artifact and rewrite the <repositories> element of it. That's why you specify a mirror. And that's why it is in your settings.xml and not in pom.xml. It is custom to your setup.

The repositories that are no longer visible under their own address should be specified in the mirrors section.

Comment: That makes it sound like a bug, since the only repo being looked up is central.

Comment: Actually, the pom for shrinkwrap-bom doesn't contain a ```repositories``` section, but only a ```distributionManagement``` section, and neither do their parents (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is transitive dependencies with scope import. 
I solved it for hibernate-validator version 6.0.13.Final by adding the following dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha-8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Issue on the Maven bugtracker:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6397
They promise to fix it in Maven version 3.6.3.

Comment: Sadly this issue was since marked as no-fix. But at least the issue allows the maven maintainers to share their view.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to [Sergey comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58410780/13608717)  - just want to mention that given dependencies should be placed inside **dependencyManagement** tag

Comment: This should be a comment, not a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

SandorRacz's advice to create a mirror worked for me as well. Thanks!!
So while building I was getting the following error in my error logs:

```
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.2 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): HTTPS Required (501) @ org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.10.Final,
```

For the sake of clarity, here is how my settings.xml looked like after creating the mirror. (I hope it saves somebody's time)

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
                <id>central-repo</id>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central-proxy</id>
        <name>central-proxy</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <mirrorOf>central-repo</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```